# how to duplicate entire model/controller/view for a different asset type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-duplication

sorry for the newbie question: I have an app which has projects with different asset types (docs, videos, etc.) I'd like to add another asset for audio with identical functionality to the video one. Is there a way I can easily duplicate model/controller/view/table changing 'video(s)' to 'audio(s)'?

Comment: there goes DRY :-) if they are so similar, why not use the same MVC ? well, if you do need seperate tables, you could have one model extend the other and specify its table name...

Comment: why not create a module that would package these functionalities ? Or just use inheritance. Or even inheritance with an extra topping of metaprogramming if you feel like fancy behaviour... it's really up to you and what you're trying to achieve. Just make some research on design patterns if you feel lost (i find Addison Wesley's "design patterns in ruby" book nice on this topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a `Module` using `ActiuveSupport::Convern` that contains all the methods you need in the model then you can `include` the Module in the models to extend the models with the methods contained in your Module. Like This:

```
module AwsomeModule
     include ActiveSupport::Concern
     module ClassMethods
          # awesome class methods here
     end
     module InstanceMethods
          # awesome instance methods here
     end
end
```

Then in Model simply include your Module. For the views you can use Partials and give them the object via the `object` and `as` options like this:

```
render 'layouts/awesome_partial', :object => @instance_var, :as => :data
```

Then in the Partial you cann access the object given using the variable `data`.